# Is there a spark configuration for the default path for the saveAsTable command?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to save a dataframe as a table and I'm wondering if there is a default path configuration I can set to make my life easier.

I understand that this works:

```
df.write.saveAsTable("mytable", path='s3a://mybucket/mybucketlocation')
```

but is it possible to have  this command

```
df.write.saveAsTable("mytable")
```

achieve the same role with spark configurations?

Currently I have this configuration set, but it's not doing the trick.

```
('spark.sql.warehouse.dir', 's3a://mybucket/mybucketlocation')
```

Comment: According to the manuals it should work. Strange.

Comment: could it possibly have anything to do with the default database location? is there another configuration for that